# httptest.NewRequest set Context stub

Tags: unit-testing, http, go, stub

I am creating a request stub in order to pass it to function under the tested:

```
request := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
```

**Question**: can I also stub `Context` object for this request by adding `request-uuid` Value to it?

Comment: There's no reason to stub it, just use `context.WithValue` to add the value to a real context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have the `request`, you can do whatever you want to with it before you hand it over.

Use [`Request.Context()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) to access its context, use [`context.WithValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#WithValue) to derive a new [`context.Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/#Context) with your key-value in it, and use [`Request.WithContext()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WithContext) to acquire a new [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) with the new context:

```
request := httptest.NewRequest("GET", "http://example.com/foo", nil)
ctx := request.Context()
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, "request-uuid", "myvalue")
request = request.WithContext(ctx)

// now request's context contains the "request-uuid" key
```